# Removing an item from a multidimentional Javascript array, based on property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I'm using KnockoutJS and have a multidimensional observable array (object?):

```
self.navItems = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "test1", children: [
        { name: "test1child1", children: [] },
        { name: "test1child2", children: [] }
    ]},
    { name: "test2", children: [] },
]);
```

I'd like to be able to remove one of the objects, based on a property value. In other works, I'd like to do something this:

```
removeNavItem("test1child2");
```

I've written a function but can't get it to work because it's looking for 'test1child2' as a property, not a value.

```
self.removeNavItem = function (itemName) {
    var item = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.navItems(), function (item) {
        if (item.name === itemName) { // this seems to work correctly
            delete self.navItems[itemName]; // this doesn't, because it tests property, not value
        }
    });
};
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/bjFeb/2/)

**EDIT:**

I didn't know about KO's built in remove/removeAll methods.

Thanks to the commentors below, I have it partially working but when I try to remove something inside of children[], it removes the entire parent as well.

```
removeNavItem = function (itemName) {
    var items = self.navItems.remove(function (item) {
        for (i = 0; i < item.children.length; i++) {
            if (item.children[i].name === itemName) {
                return item.children[i].name;
            }
        }
        return item.name === itemName;
    });
};
```

[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjFeb/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to use it on any level, then pass in the array that you want to remove it from:

```
self.removeNavItem = function (obsArray, itemName)
{
    obsArray.remove(function(item) { return item.name === itemName });
};
```

Then you can call this on each element:

```
click: function() { $root.removeNavItem($parent.children, $data.name); }
```

I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjFeb/8/), and it works, though you have to make all children arrays observable arrays for it to work.

Comment: Thank you! 1 issue I'm having with this that it seems to work for top level items but no second or third level items.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I think I'll be able to use an if(item.children.length > 0) {...} before the return to get it working. I'll play around with it.

Comment: Getting closer but still no luck. If you have a min, please check out my edit above.

Comment: I haven't looked, but see if my updated answer helps, as it gets round having to work out which array you are in.

Comment: Updated fiddle, and my solution works, once you make all children observable arrays, rather than normal js arrays.

Comment: Good call! Works great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way to do this. Knockout provides a `remove()` that can use a function to remove the matching items:

```
self.removeNavItem = function (itemName) {
    var items = self.navItems.remove( function (item) { 
        return item.name === itemName; 
    });
};
```

(It's mentioned in the 'Remove and RemoveAll' section in the [observableArrays documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html))

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need a function that make a search on n level of recursion

```
 function del(obj,val){
   $.each(obj,function(i,j){
       if(j['name'] == val){
          delete(j);
          return false;
       }else if(j['children'].length!=0){
           del(j['children'],val);
         }
   })

 }
```

this function take two arguments your object and the value to search, you can modify it to suit your case.